# Why does the variance of the estimate of coefficients blow up when (XTX)-1 is singular?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, linear-algebra

I have been getting my hands on linear regression and multicolinearity problem, mainly trying to approach it within a sense of linear algebra. I found this pdf from CMU as to colinearity.

[image]

It says the variance will blow up when XTX is singular. However, as far as I know, isn't it impossible anyway to calculate the invertible matrix of the singular matrix? Why does it blow up? I know it more sounds like a linear algebra problem, but it would be awesome if I could acquire some intuition behind this operation.

Thank you!

Comment: **The quoted statement is wrong.**  When $x^\prime x$ is "close to being non-invertible" (whatever that might mean!), the variances can still be arbitrarily *small.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a singular square matrix has zero determinant, and the taking inverse corresponds to the following formula:
$$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\text{adj}(A)$$
where [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) has no operation to blow up the expression. So, singular matrix makes the expression infinite, so the inverse doesn't exist.

You can visualize this situation by thinking about (informally speaking) *nearly singular* matrices, where for example the determinant is close to $0$, but not exactly, e.g. $\det A=10^{-50}$. The inverse will have entries at scale $10^{50}$ which will blow the expression.

Comment: This reasoning is invalid--and there are many counterexamples.  The elements of $A^{-1}$ indeed may become arbitrarily *small* as $A$ approaches a singular matrix.  You haven't accounted for the possibility that the sizes of the elements of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ are comparable to (or smaller than) $\operatorname{det}(A).$